# Is there some form of blocking in place for rejected suggested edits by anonymous users?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

When a registered user gets enough suggested edits rejected, they're blocked from suggesting edits for a number of days.

I've always assumed it was a user-level block, but what about anonymous suggested edits? Can anonymous users suggest edits with impunity, or is there a lower-level block (like, say, IP-blocking) in place, if only for anonymous users?

Comment: I can't say for sure, but it's likely. Their IP addresses are saved at any rate, as evidenced by their [consistent Gravatars](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8qXR0.png).

Comment: @lunboks Oh... this puts down my theory...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Yes** there is an IP level block in place as well. The logic is exactly the same as it is for registered users, except that the key is the IP Address.

Answer (score 2):

I would presume that the block is an IP block, because of the fact that when they block users from asking on meta, it is also an IP block and I'm sure that they've taken the anonymous suggested edit users into consideration.

I looked high and low for more details on how the edit-blocking system works and found nothing, so some clarification from someone who knows for sure would be nice.