# Are there any proactive ways to deal with repeated anonymous spam edits?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, anonymous

I know that anonymous edits are tracked and eventually blocked, based on the discussion in [Is there some form of blocking in place for rejected suggested edits by anonymous users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118213/is-there-some-form-of-blocking-in-place-for-rejected-suggested-edits-by-anonymou) However, I wonder if there are any proactive options available (either for moderators or other users) when a particular IP is clearly a spambot.

For example, the "anonymous" tab of the suggested edit stats on Android Enthusiasts currently looks like this:

[image]

There are at least another two edits of a similar nature with the same gravatar. After maybe two suggested edits (really, one is honestly probably enough) I think we can *pretty confidently* say it's a spambot - and even if it isn't, it's safe to say that the contributions are...well, useless. As far as I know, my only recourse is to simply wait for the auto-ban to kick in, but that seems almost silly in a lot of ways.

Are there any more proactive options for dealing with this scenario? If not, would it be possible to add some, so that users aren't needlessly tasked with rejecting clearly pointless edits until the auto-ban kicks in?

Comment: I think the blocking *is* the proactive option.  So you want the triggers to be more sensitive, I guess?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: That or some way to manually ban/blacklist IPs (or simply *request* a ban from the team), although I'm not sure how unwieldy that would be or what floodgates that opens. Alternatively, maybe stricter filters on the content would help, since the ones I've highlighted above are quite obviously spam. More sensitive triggering of the block would get a hearty seal of approval from me, too, though I have no idea where that limit currently stands (I assume that's kind of hush-hush to prevent skirting it).