# What happen when multiple anonymous suggested edits are declined?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there some form of blocking in place for rejected suggested edits by anonymous users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118213/is-there-some-form-of-blocking-in-place-for-rejected-suggested-edits-by-anonymou)

On *English Language & Usage*, there have been some anonymous suggested edits which radically changed the answer.

- https://english.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/12202
- https://english.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/12201
- https://english.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/12200
- https://english.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/12199
- https://english.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/12198

All those suggested edits are for answers given to the same question.

What happens when too much suggested edits done from anonymous users are rejected?
Are anonymous suggested edits blocked for X days?
Is there any other block for the user anonymously suggesting edits that are rejected?

Comment: Just be glad they get rejected... On SO such edits come close to getting approved (and some actually do get approved). For example: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/827021 & http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/827006

Comment: @YannisRizos Who in his right mind could reject zebras and pandas?

Comment: Looks like someone didn't like that Obama won.

Comment: @Yannis yeah, typical example of approval troll; just hope there won't be too many of those or the devs will start dealing with them somehow.