# Temporarily ban anonymous edits if an edit is spam/vandalism

Tags: discussion, feature-request, suggested-edits, edit-ban

Take a look at [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2880366). It was rejected as spam/vandalism, but was suggested by an anonymous user. Should we temporarily ban edits from an IP address that has an edit rejected as spam/vandalism? Maybe flag the edit and if a moderator deems it spam/vandalism, then ban?

Comment: There is a non-trivial possibility that this is one of our problem users from Physics.SE who has exhibited such behavior before. However he usually access the sites through proxy farms, so it is difficult to do anything permanently effective.

Comment: @dmckee maybe ban _proxy farms_? Wikipedia bans known proxies, but I guess they get so much vandalism it's easier to find them...

Comment: Cole, that sounds great, but the Opera browser people use a huge caching proxy to give their browsers a little bit of a speed boost. On Opera mobile there isn't even a option to *not* use it, so nearly all Opera users comes from one Class A address space. The team has not been willing to ban that large a potential user base.

Answer (score 11):

Maybe ban edits from that IP address, but only for anonymous users.  There are many users who share an IP address and I don't think we should interfere with their activity because of one bad (anonymous) egg.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. Kindof like wikipedia.

Comment: [That's already the case](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/121366/152859), probably the spammer keeps changing IP addresses.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd does the IP ban prevent logged in users from editing?

Comment: @Cole as far as I can tell then yes, edit ban is IP-based, not just account. (relevant only for suggested edits, full edit privilege can't be banned it was discussed today)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd what do you mean "full edit privilege"? An anonymous edit has to be "suggested".

Comment: @Cole you asked about logged in users, so thought maybe you mean 2K users as well.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd ok now I'm confused. The IP ban bans anonymous edits, but does it ban logged in users with less than 2k? If so, then that should be changed. If not, feel free to close this as a duplicate.

Comment: @Cole my bad. After reading "Yes there is an IP level block in place as well. The logic is exactly the same as it is for registered users, except that the key is the IP Address" again it's clear the IP ban is only for anonymous users. Still, this isn't a dupe as other questions only ask what's the policy. :)