# If a user suggests an edit that gets rejected as "spam or vandalism", does he/she lose 100 reputation?

Tags: support, reputation, suggested-edits, spam, offensive

If a user writes a post that gets marked as "spam" or "rude or abusive", he/she loses 100 reputation.  Does this also happen when the user suggests an edit that gets rejected as "spam or vandalism"?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No, this doesn't happen. I'm sure somebody would have noticed and/or complained about it on Meta, and it's not listed in any of the questions here, including the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7237/295232).

It would take only 2 users (or even 1 in case of the author or a moderator reviewing the edit) to impose this penalty on the user who suggested the edit, that seems too prone for mistakes (or maybe even targeting a specific user).

Largely speaking, all of the rejection reasons have the same effect. The exception is that [suggested edits rejected as spam aren't visible for anonymous users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/346542/4751173), and may result in the edit being fed into SpamRam.

Comment: I *thought* the IP address gets blocked if an anonymous user suggests an edit which is rejected as spam, but [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/121366/295232) seems to suggest it applies to other rejection reasons too.

Comment: It's probably also worth noting that suggested edits can be made by anonymous users (eg: they don't even have an account) - therefore, there'd not be an account to impose a penalty against...

Comment: Yes.  As "spam", "rude or abusive", and "in need of moderator intervention" flags have more extra weight / high priority than the other flags, it appears as if "spam or vandalism" and "causes harm" rejection reasons are **slightly** heavier than the other reasons, but the gap is not as wide.

Comment: @SonictheReinstateMonica-hog - What is "SpamRam"?  Is it the stuff that says "You cannot post at this time due to volume of spam or abuse originating from your network... blah blah blah"?

Comment: @MaikaSakuranomiya SpamRam is the system that blocks the spammers. It will automatically block source IP addresses and ranges on the list. So if anything is fed into it, the system will act against it.

Comment: Does SpamRam involve the text I have mentioned in my previous comment?  That's is what I am asking.

Comment: @MaikaSakuranomiya The text you see is part of the user interface, not part of SpamRam. SpamRam is a system used by the team, developers etc., it doesn't communicate with the users.

Comment: @SonictheReinstateMonica-hog - oh yes... I see.